# EmberJS: Posting Form to Controller, Data Bound to Model

Tags: ember.js

I see conflicting information on this.  But this is what I'm currently doing.  In my template, I have a form with the following action helper:

```
<button {{action "save" song}}>Save</button>
```

In my controller, I have the following:

```
App.SongsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  title: '',

  actions: {
    save: function() {
      console.log(this.get('title'));
    }
  }
});
```

I also have a Song model defined and ideally, I'd like the values I submit from the form to be bound to that model and then just be able to reference the Song model in my controller, rather than getting properties from the controller and manually populating my model.  Something like:

```
App.SongsNewController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

  actions: {
    save: function(song) {
       song.save();
    }
  }
});
```

I'm pretty sure this is possible (I hope anyway), I just am not finding the docs on that anywhere or am missing them.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have array controller, I would assume that you would be iterating over your songs like this:

```
//songsNew.hbs
{{#each}}
   {{input type="text" value=name}}
   <button {{action "save" this}}>Save</button>
{{/each}}
```

Then you can have the "save" action as you mentioned in your post with song model passed as an argument.
But if you have itemController defined, then the action goes to the itemController itself, not the arrayController. If you want your array controller to handle the save, then you might have to set the target to the action as follows:

```
<button {{action "save" this target=parentController}}>Save</button>
```

EDIT:

In the SongNewRoute, define the model as:

```
model: function(){ return this.get('store').createRecord('song');}
```

This gives you new empty song model, you can bind your form to this model and when you make save action, the data gets persisted in db.

Comment: I've edited my post.  Thanks for the response.  I meant to have an ObjectController.  Does that change anything?

Comment: In that case, your save function will just have : this.get('model').save(); because the model of your controller will be song model.